# Real meaning on "ELF 64-bit LSB shared object"

Tags: executable, elf

How can ELF 64-bit LSB shared object be executable that is readilt executed/launched right away, isn't it opposing the word terms "shared object" (Windows equivalent to dynamic link) ?

Comment: So and dll is also "executable" so nothing wrong. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format

Comment: ELF, Executable and Linkable Format, is used for program code, that is compiled from source code, for example compiled from C code (different from interpreted code for example bash shellscripts or python code).

Comment: it is possible for shared objects to become executable in the elf format.  here is an example of someone doing that: https://bhushanverma.blogspot.com/2008/06/how-to-run-shared-library-on-linux.html